# Really long starttransfer_time over curl

Tags: php, curl

I'm racking my brain trying to figure out why I'm getting such long start transfer times when using curl to get the content of a page on the same domain.

http://dragon.pbndev.net/?rah_external_output=team_pages. Getting this page in my browser the response is ~200ms, same page over curl my starttransfer_time is ~16 seconds.

If I switch the below to say https://www.google.com I can get the response really fast, just about the same as if I hit the target url in my browser.

Lots of these options I picked up from other "my curl requests are not working" questions here. I just can't figure out why the response time is so long.

I've also tried the same url above with `file_get_contents()` and I get an empty response.

```
$ch = curl_init();
$getTemplateFromDomain = 'http://dragon.pbndev.net/?rah_external_output=team_pages';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $getTemplateFromDomain);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: close'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4 );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 25);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
$errStr = curl_error($ch);
$errNum = curl_errno($ch);
$head = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT);
$ci = curl_getinfo($ch);
var_dump(array('head' => $head, 'error_string' => $errStr, 'error_number' =>  $errNum, 'curl_info' =>  $ci, 'response' => $response));
```

This is the response I get from the var_dump, SO i can get the content, it just take a very long time.

```
array (size=5)
    'head' => boolean false
    'error_string' => string '' (length=0)
    'error_number' => int 0
    'curl_info' => 
        array (size=22)
        'url' => string 'http://dragon.pbndev.net/?rah_external_output=team_pages' (length=56)
        'content_type' => string 'text/plain; charset=utf-8' (length=25)
        'http_code' => int 200
        'header_size' => int 562
        'request_size' => int 222
        'filetime' => int -1
        'ssl_verify_result' => int 0
        'redirect_count' => int 0
        'total_time' => float 16.195335
        'namelookup_time' => float 0.001552
        'connect_time' => float 0.001802
        'pretransfer_time' => float 0.002
        'size_upload' => float 0
        'size_download' => float 7007
        'speed_download' => float 432
        'speed_upload' => float 0
        'download_content_length' => float -1
        'upload_content_length' => float 0
        'starttransfer_time' => float 16.19518
        'redirect_time' => float 0
        'certinfo' => 
             array (size=0)
                 empty
        'redirect_url' => string '' (length=0)
        'response' => string '<!doctype html>
            <!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
            <!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
            <!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js lt-ie9" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
            <!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
            <head>
                <meta charset="utf-8">

                <meta name="description" content="Lake Bemidji Dragon Boat Festival's website">
                <meta name="keywords" content="Bemidji, Minne'... (length=7007)
```

Ultimately I'm going to cache the result in memcache so I don't have to get it very time, but I'd like to figure out why it's taking so long in the first place.

Comment: web page wont even load for me

Comment: really? blank page, 404, or something else?

Comment: simply sits there trying to load, does not even bother time out.

Comment: Have you solved it yet? I got the same issue and it's 2016 now... I think it's the same issue here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39614980/php-curl-localhost-is-slow-when-making-concurrent-requests